# jssor active thumbnail border

Tags: css

I am using the jssor thumbnail scroller and have got almost everything how I want it but I am stuck on one last thing.

A border on the selected thumbnail image, I want the border on the thumbnail that is selected to be a different colour to the ones not selected.

Using the skin 01 I have made all bits of CSS under it to a width and height of 70px as this sorts out the annoying problem of some borders like the top and right border being 2px when you specify 1px but now I want the thumbnail that is selected currently to have a different colour border.

What class bellow on skin 01 is the bit of CSS for the currently selected thumbnail?

```
 /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
 /*
 .jssort01 .p (normal)
 .jssort01 .p:hover   (normal mouseover)
 .jssort01 .p.pav     (active)
 .jssort01 .p.pdn     (mousedown)
 */

 .jssort01 {
 position: absolute;
 /* size of thumbnail navigator container */
 width: 233px;
 height: 90px;
 }

 .jssort01 .p {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 72px;
 height: 72px;
 }

 .jssort01 .t {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: none;
 }

 .jssort01 .w {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }

 .jssort01 .c {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 border: red 1px solid;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 background: url(../img/t01.png) -800px -800px no-repeat;
 _background: none;
 }

 .jssort01 .pav .c {
 top: 2px;
 _top: 0px;
 left: 2px;
 _left: 0px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 border: red 0px solid;
 _border: red 1px solid;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 }

 .jssort01 .p:hover .c {
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 border: blue 1px solid;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 }

 .jssort01 .p.pdn .c {
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 border: red 1px solid;
 }

 * html .jssort01 .c, * html .jssort01 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01 .pav .c {
 /* ie quirks mode adjust */
 width /**/: 72px;
 height /**/: 72px;
 }
```

I have played about with all the border settings above changing colours with test colours changing border px sizes but I cant for the life of me figure out what in the above code deals with the border on the automaticly selected thumbnail.

In the above CSS it lists this as a TIP

.jssort01 .p.pav     (active)

But there is no **.jssort01 .p.pav** in the actual code

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

not sure i use right Jssor demo, but if im right, so here what you want:
`.jssort01 .t {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
     border: 1px solid white; <!-- or whatever color you want -->
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer **Henry Varro** but it had to do with the CSS and also the **$Align** in the JS.

**$Align** is now at **121**

and skin css is as bellow

```
            .jssort01 .pav .c {
            width: 70px;
            height: 70px;
            border: blue 1px solid;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }
```

The colour's where just for testing and will be changed when integrated into my script

Thanks for the help though.

It would help if the jssor team wrote a tutorial on what skin CSS element changes what.